# Auto enable flash for site in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flash

I'm using Uploadify.swf file to upload certain type of files to my dropbox account. However when the flash is not detected or it is not enabled, the files are not uploaded. As being a developer i have generated a popup message for this issue. But I'm trying to find if there is any way the flash for the site gets enabled automatically, without done manually.

Similarly the swf files is not supported on Firefox. It works fine on Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                 $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
                     swf: 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
                     uploader: 'Upload.ashx',
                     cancelImg: 'Content/cancel.png',
                     auto: true,
                     multi: true,
                     method: 'POST',
                     //fileTypeExts: '*.jpg; *.png; *.gif; *.bmp; *.jpeg; *.JPG; *.pdf; *.doc; *.docx;',
                     buttonText: 'Upload File',
                     width: 130,
                     onUploadSuccess: function (file, data, response) {
                         console.log("sucess");

                         console.log(data);

                         var filName = file.name + Math.random();
                         console.log(filName);

                         $("#attachedfiles").append("<tr><td>" + file.name + "</td><td><a  onclick=\"deleteHostTable(this);\"   href = 'javascript:;'>[x]</a></td></tr>");

                     },
                     onFallback: function () {
                         alert('Flash was not detected  or flash version is not supported.');


                     }
                 });
             });
```

Comment: I don't think there is (and I hope there never will). Flash is disabled by default in many modern browser for a very good reason and that is security. A lot of Flash users do not have the latest version and are vulnerable to attack. If there was a way to enable it without user intervention, many malicious websites and banner ads would use it.

Comment: So is there any other plugin that doesn't require any flash support or any external file and uploads file normally?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Chrome already disable flash by default. While an end-user still can enable it, flash technology seems to be outdated.

I use a third-party upload component to [upload files to Amazon](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxFileManagerAndUploadDemos/UploadControl/UploadToAmazon.aspx). It also supports [DropBox upload](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxFileManagerAndUploadDemos/UploadControl/UploadToDropbox.aspx) out of the box.